# How to virtualize Nodes running Hadoop and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark, virtualization

I have a few questions concerning a virtualized Cluster consisting of Hadoop and MongoDB.

Some information about my data pipeline:

- I do not frequently transfer data from HDFS to MongoDB, but sometimes I will have to do it.
- I use HDFS as the data lake with some data warehousing capabilities offered by Hive.
- I plan to use Spark to run analytic tasks on the MongoDB data.
- I *might* use Spark to run some tasks on the HDFS data (not that likely at the moment)
- I am aware of the fact that separating Hadoop and MongoDB on different virtual nodes, this might introduce network latency when writing data from HDFS to MongoDB or vice versa.

Questions:

1. Are there downsides of running the Hadoop ecosystem (HDFS, YARN, Hive, Spark to name a few services) on the same virtualized machine as MongoDB?
2. Are the virtualized Hadoop and MongoDB nodes supposed to be "always-on" or can the nodes be shut down when in longer idle state? Are there downsides of shutting them down - except the longer restart time for the next analytic tasks?
3. Spark is somewhat coupled to the Hadoop ecosystem. Which is the preferred way to run the cluster?

   - running Hadoop and MongoDB on my virtual nodes together
   - running Hadoop and MongoDB separately, but only have Spark on the Hadoop nodes
   - running Hadoop and MongoDB separately, and have Spark on both the Hadoop and MongoDB nodes

I couldn't find sufficient information about how to build a cluster like this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **2.** HDFS and MongoDB are used to *store* data and keep it *available* -- usually with a replication factor, to allow for transient node failures. But if you shut down several nodes and make them unavailable, then MANY files will suddenly become under-replicated, and a "replication storm" will ensue to re-create an extra copy on one of the remaining nodes. Do you really want that?? Or did you mean a global, ordered shutdown of the whole cluster??

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes, in fact I was implying a global ordered shutdown of, for example, all MongoDB nodes because we do not need them. I don't think it makes that much sense - especially because the cost for the cluster when in idle state is not that high. I agree that always-on is a must for the cluster. What about separating MongoDB and HDFS though?